# Leer Excel en C#

Tags: c#, oledb

Estimados que tengan buen día, estoy en un problema cuando trato de leer un excel formato xlsx, ya lo he realizado antes y nunca me había pasado. resulta que es una aplicacion de consola y al momento de abrir la conexion Oledb este se cae y dice external table is not in the expected format pero lo raro va acá. cuando abro mi archivo excel lo lee sin problemas estando el archivo abierto. Pero cuando el archivo esta cerrado no lo lee y se cae en el punto que les mencioné.
Acá esta el extracto del codigo:

```
string path = Convert.ToString(dnom1);
string filename = Convert.ToString(Path.GetFileName(path));               
string filepath = @"C:\Users\joel.baez.silvestre\Desktop\Descargas editadas\Listos\TramoLineaLectura\Excel\\" + filename;
string constr = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;""", filepath);            
Console.WriteLine("Archivo descargado y extraído exitosamente");
OleDbConnection Econ;
Econ = new OleDbConnection(constr);
string qTotal = string.Format("Select * from[Sheet1$]");
string qTotalvalores = string.Format("Select * from[Sheet1$B12:H755]");
OleDbCommand ETotal = new OleDbCommand(qTotal, Econ);
OleDbCommand Etotal2 = new OleDbCommand(qTotalvalores, Econ);

Econ.Open(); // en este punto se cae cuando el excel esta cerrado

// Creacion de Dataset para cada uno de los contructores
DataSet dsTotal = new DataSet();
DataSet dsTotal2 = new DataSet();
OleDbDataAdapter odaTotal = new OleDbDataAdapter(qTotal, Econ);
OleDbDataAdapter odaTotal2 = new OleDbDataAdapter(qTotalvalores, Econ);
Econ.Close();
odaTotal.Fill(dsTotal);
odaTotal2.Fill(dsTotal2);
```

Comment: Intentaste revisar si tu xlsx tiene alguna pestaña escondida, aveces OLEDB falla cuando ahi pestañas escondidas o podria ser el archivo temporal ~foo.xlsx que se genera cuando abres el excel ?
Btw estas generando el archivo en algun server?

Comment: Hay varias librerias de NuGet que tienen todo preparado para leer y escribir en excels.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo usar https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML/

```
 XLWorkbook ArchivoExcel = new XLWorkbook(@"C:\Users\...\Desktop\calculo.xlsx");//ruta del libro excel
 var HojaExcel = ArchivoExcel.Worksheet(1);//hojas del libro        

 foreach (IXLRow fila in HojaExcel.Rows())//recorrer las filas
 {
      var valor1 =  fila.Cell(1).GetValue<String>();//obtienes los valores //string o el tipo que desees
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Con ClosedXMl te ahorras unas cuantas líneas de código, además te queda más limpio el código y por lo tanto más fácil de mantener, si a eso sumas cambiar tus string.Format por interpolación $"" y Path.Combine para el directorio vas a ganar en rendimiento.